# Generate graph like PISA

Tags: graph

Please help me to plot the graph like in PISA report
[image: https://www.oecd.org/pisa/PISA-results_ENGLISH.png]

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far

Comment: i have mean marks of different schools in four subjects